# Drop Down menu doesn't display in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

I need help figuring out why the menu I have created does not work properly in IE.  I'm currently in a HTML/CSS class so my experience level is limited.  I'm kind of just googling things and checking my book as I go.

I created this menu from a tutorial I found after googling "css drop down menu".  I'm pretty proud of it but I can't figure out why it does not display properly in Internet Explorer.  It seems to work great in Firefox and Chrome, and more importantly, on ipads.  My company currently uses a java menu and I'd like to replace it with this.

Here is the link:

http://net.saddleback.edu/hyosafi0/CIM271A/random/menutest/menu.htm

I would appreciate any advice on why it does not work in IE or where I should start looking in my code for errors.  I think it has something to do with declaring a doctype but I'm not sure.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `<li>` tag on the second Home link.

Also, try inserting `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your html file. This will get IE out of Quirks mode, which can solve some problems in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I thought it would be something much more complex!!